# Todolist node js - modify a todo.

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm beginner in HTML and Node js, so I've decided to train myself at it doing a todolist, from the french website openclassroom.

I've took the solution code for adding, deleting and display the todos of the todolist and tried on my own to rename a task, in vain...

I'de like to step by step: 
-open a text input once the unicode pen symbol next to a todo is clicked 
-and once the text is sent by clicking on submit button, then modify the selected item

What I now got is that always and only the first element is modified when I click on the pen symbol. I think it's due to the form called while i'm printing the list, because this form does not have a unique ID.

Here is my code :

```js
var express = require('express');
var session = require('cookie-session'); // Charge le middleware de sessions
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // Charge le middleware de gestion des paramètres
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

var app = express();


/* On utilise les sessions */
app.use(session({secret: 'sess1'}))


/* S'il n'y a pas de todolist dans la session,
on en crée une vide sous forme d'array avant la suite */
.use(function(req, res, next){
    if (typeof(req.session.todolist) == 'undefined') {
        req.session.todolist = [];
    }
    next();
})

/* On affiche la todolist et le formulaire */
.get('/todo', function(req, res) { 
    res.render('todo.ejs', {todolist: req.session.todolist});
})

/* On ajoute un élément à la todolist */
.post('/todo/ajouter/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    if (req.body.newtodo != '') {
        req.session.todolist.push(req.body.newtodo);
    }
    res.redirect('/todo');
})

/*On modifie un élément de la todolist */
.post('/todo/modifier/:id', urlencodedParser,function(req, res){
 
 let i0 = parseInt(req.params.id);
 if(req.params.id != '' && Number.isInteger(i0))
 {
  console.log(i0);
  req.session.todolist[i0]=req.body.itemupdate;
 }
 res.redirect('/todo');
})

/* Supprime un élément de la todolist */
.get('/todo/supprimer/:id', function(req, res) {
    if (req.params.id != '') {
        req.session.todolist.splice(req.params.id, 1);
    }
    res.redirect('/todo');
})

/* On redirige vers la todolist si la page demandée n'est pas trouvée */
.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.redirect('/todo');
})

.listen(8080);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ma todolist</title>
        <style>
            a {text-decoration: none; color: black;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Ma todolist</h1>
  <script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     
  <script type="text/javascript">
   //showhide the modifying text
     function showHideForm(formid) {
     var _form = document.getElementById(formid);
     _form.style.display = (_form.style.display != "block") ? "block" : "none";
     return false;
     }
  </script>
  
  

        <ul>
        <% todolist.forEach(function(todo, index) { %>
            <li>
    <%= todo %> 
    <button <a href="/todo/supprimer/<%= index %>"> ✘</a>
    <script>
     var uniqueIDform= "hf"+<%=index%>;
     var uniqueIDitem= "itm"+<%=index%>;
    </script>
    
    <button onclick="return showHideForm('uniqueIDform');">✎</button>
    
    <form action="/todo/modifier/<%= index %>" id="uniqueIDform" style="display: none;" method="post">
      <label for="uniqueIDitem"></label>
      <input type="text" name="itemUpdate" id="uniqueIDitem" autofocus/>
      <input type="submit" value="OK" />
     </form> 
   </li>
        <% }); %>
        </ul>

        <form action="/todo/ajouter/" method="post">
            <p>
                <label for="newtodo">Que dois-je faire ?</label>
                <input type="text" name="newtodo" id="newtodo" autofocus />
                <input type="submit" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

*This is not actually the answer to the question, but it was too large for a comment!*

The first thing I can tell you is that you should be using a `PUT` request type for modifying a TODO. Whilst `POST` *can* be used to update data, it's often a good practice to not do it and keep your API consistent - learn more about REST API [here](https://spring.io/understanding/REST) :

- `GET` is to get data
- `POST` is to create data
- `PUT` is to update data
- `PATCH` is to update specific fields of data
- `DELETE` is to remove data

Now that this is cleared, I didn't really fully understand your code, but here's the conceptual answer to the problem:

To update something you will need the ID of said item, or some identifier of it. You need to make sure this ID gets passed through in the request, otherwise your backend won't know which data needs to be updated. In concept, you can get this ID in multiple ways, such as storing the last clicked pen symbol ID somewhere to make it part of the request.

It seems that, if you are **always** updating the first one, that somehow you're always sending this ID as a zero, and it might be getting the data at position `[0]`. I'd start by taking a look at the request in chrome - open the developer tools, go into network, refresh the page, and modify something and save, and you can see a new request being sent, and click it to see it's information, which should include the ID.

If that ID doesn't match the one you edited, it means your problem is in the frontend. Narrow your issue down like this, and try to fix it.

**EDIT:** if I had to guess, your `<form action=...<% = index %>` is where the issue is.

Comment: Hi Ted, Thanks for showing me this tool in browser to see what request we have. Actually I'm using Mozilla so maybe things are a bit different. Though I managed to get the things working using "req.query" and the get method, instead of the put method... Does it make a big difference?